# "use of moved value" when trying to use the same resource two times

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Here's the code:

```
extern crate tempdir;

use std::env;
use tempdir::*;

#[test]
fn it_installs_component() {
    let current_dir = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let home_dir = env::home_dir().unwrap();
    let tmp_dir = env::temp_dir();

    println!("The current directory is: {}", current_dir.display());
    println!("The home directory is: {}", home_dir.display());
    println!("The temporary directory is: {}", tmp_dir.display());

    let stage_dir = TempDir::new_in(tmp_dir.as_path(), "Components-Test");

    let components_dir = TempDir::new_in(stage_dir.unwrap().path(), "Components");

    // This is "offending line"
    // let components_make_dir = TempDir::new_in(stage_dir.unwrap().path(), "Components.make");

    println!("---- {:?}", components_dir.unwrap().path());
    //println!("---- {:?}", components_make_dir.unwrap().path());
}
```

If the offending line is commented out the code compiles fine. If I uncomment it, I start getting an error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stage_dir`
  --> src/main.rs:21:51
   |
18 |         let components_dir = TempDir::new_in(stage_dir.unwrap().path(), "Components");
   |                                              --------- value moved here
...
21 |         let components_make_dir = TempDir::new_in(stage_dir.unwrap().path(), "Components.make");
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `stage_dir` has type `std::result::Result<tempdir::TempDir, std::io::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I understand the problem is that I move `stage_dir` when I use it the first time, but I can't see how to share `stage_dir` between those two sub-folders as I will need to access them both in my test.

I tried playing with `&stage_dir` but that produced some other warnings even more obscure to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TempDir::new` gives you back a `Result<TempDir>`. You're trying to unwrap it each time, rather than unwrap it once to get a `TempDir`, and then share *that*.

So change

```
let stage_dir = TempDir::new_in(tmp_dir.as_path(), "Components-Test");
```

to

```
let stage_dir = TempDir::new_in(tmp_dir.as_path(), "Components-Test").unwrap();
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, now it is working! I still don't get why not-unwrapped item cannot be shared and vice versa - is there a link to somewhere or simple explanation?

Comment: I mean, you _could_ also share it, but you're not. You're trying to unwrap it twice.